# c# string to Timecode

Tags: c#, regex, timecodes

I need to build a method that can return me the string like this

`00:00:00:00`
`hh:mm:ss:fr`

If I pass 10 seconds to the method it should give the output : `00:00:10:00`, So if minutes/hours/frames are null, it should enter 00.as in this example.

```
public static string ToTimeCode(string hours, string minutes, string seconds, string frames)
    {
      string timeCodeString

       // should I do some IF loops here to check for nulls and build the timecode string

      return timeCodeString;
    }
```

Is this possible with regular expressions.

Comment: Is this an assignment that disallows using datetime?

Comment: @RedX `TimeSpan` would seem closer, but: frames != milliseconds; I *am* intrigued as to whether `int` makes more sense than `string`, though

Comment: if I turn it to int and pass it as timespan, what happens to the frames then

Comment: did you check https://github.com/ailen0ada/Timecode4net?

Comment: try it out xD @user726720

Comment: @MarcGravell I did not see it was frames. Anyway the point I was trying to make is whether this is an assignment that prevents him from using existing classes/frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

I think with a little bit of googling you could have found the answer yourself.

The unanswered question is, when for example hour is 0 do you receive `00` in the string? Or is it null? Assuming everything is as you expect you can just interpolate the string:

```
return $"{hour ?? "00"}:{minute ?? "00"}:{second ?? "00"}:{frames ?? "00"}";
```

A simple (and inefficient) C# 5.0 version as requested in the comments could be:

```
return 
   (hour == null ? "00" : hour)
   + ":"
   + (minute == null ? "00" : minute)
   + ":"
   + (second == null ? "00" : second)
   + ":"
   + (frames == null ? "00" : frames);
```

Comment: when hour is 0, I receive a "00" in the string

Comment: Does your solution work in C# 5, as it's not being recognized.

Comment: No because nowhere in your question it says that it must work in C# 5.0. String interpolation is available from 6.0 onwards. Why are you using a C# version from 2012?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp26
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ToTimeCode(null,null,"10",null));
            Console.WriteLine(ToTimeCode("1", "2", "3", "4"));

            Console.WriteLine(ToTimeCode2(null, null, "10", null));
            Console.WriteLine(ToTimeCode2("1", "2", "3", "4"));

            Console.ReadLine(); 
        }

        public static string ToTimeCode(string hours, string minutes, string seconds, string frames)
        {
            int.TryParse(hours, out int hoursInt);
            int.TryParse(minutes, out int minutesInt);
            int.TryParse(seconds, out int secondsInt);
            int.TryParse(frames, out int framesInt);
            var timespan = new TimeSpan(hoursInt, minutesInt, secondsInt, framesInt);
            return timespan.ToString("g");
        }

        public static string ToTimeCode2(string hours, string minutes, string seconds, string frames)
        {
            int.TryParse(hours, out int hoursInt);
            int.TryParse(minutes, out int minutesInt);
            int.TryParse(seconds, out int secondsInt);
            int.TryParse(frames, out int framesInt);
            var timespan = new TimeSpan(hoursInt, minutesInt, secondsInt, framesInt);
            return timespan.ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0:10:00
1:2:03:04
00.00:10:00
01.02:03:04
```

If u give wrong format or null to string parametrs, it will 0 at the output